# How to get the smallest item from the second items of a tuple list?

Tags: python

First of all sorry for the confusing title, I had no idead how to explain my problem without an example.

I have the following graph

```
graph = {
    1: [(3, 5), (4, 1),  (5, 4)],
    2: [(5, 9)],
    3: [(5, 1), (6, 1)],
    4: [(2, 11), (8, 2)],
    5: [(4, 6), (2, 6)],
    6: [(7, 1)],
    7: [(5, 7), (2, 1)],
    8: [(2, 6)],
}
```

I want to be able to get the smallest number from the second item of the tupels for a given number. For example, if I gave the function the number 1 I would want it to return the 1 from the second tupel. If the input was 4 instead I would expect it to return a 2 form the second tupel.

My current approach is `min((graph[s])[1])`, but this doesn't really work and mostly returns Index Errors.

Edit: 
I solved the problem with `(min(graph[s])[0], min(graph[s])[1])[1]` now (for some reason) it works in all cases (the problems were with lists that only contained one tupel).

Comment: Incase of ``5`` what will the output ??

Comment: I think your question is not clear. Do you mean to get the smallest element of the second tuple, or get the smallest tuple according to the tuples' second elements? If it's the former, what will happen for input `6`?

Comment: The answer you accepted is not corresponding to your initial questio, the answer you accepted, just gives the smallest number between all number in the the tuples, no matter the position in the list or in the tuple

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
s = 7
print(min(min(graph[s], key= lambda t:min(t))))
```

Comment: What works is `(min(graph[s])[0], min(graph[s])[1])[1]`

Comment: @jonas How is this the accepted answer when it gives wrong results according to your expected in the question (for example for `s=1`)???

Comment: `(min(graph[s])[0],min(graph[s])[1])` is basically equivalent to `min(graph[s])`...

Comment: Thank to @Tomerikoo point out my wrong. I am sorry for rushing to answer the question. I have edited and test it carefully, now the answer is right.

Comment: @jonas I have edited my answer and test it carefully, please review it.

Comment: Now it just returns the smallest number in that key between all tuples. Doesn't seem related to the question...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes when dealing when pair like `2: [(5, 9)]` where there is juse 1 item, when accessing `[1]` this will fail, you gotta check the length before

```
def get_min(graph, key, position=1):
    values = graph[key]
    if len(values) > position:
      return min(values[position])
    return -1


graph = {1: [(3, 5), (4, 1), (5, 4)],2:[(5, 9)],3: [(5, 1), (6, 1)],4: [(2, 11), (8, 2)],
         5: [(4, 6), (2, 6)],6: [(7, 1)],7: [(5, 7), (2, 1)],8: [(2, 6)],}

for k,v in graph.items():
  print(k, get_min(graph, k))

1 => 1
2 => -1
3 => 1
4 => 2
5 => 2
6 => -1
7 => 1
8 => -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def get_smallest_num(key):
    return min(map(lambda x: x[1], graph[key]))

print(get_smallest_num(1)) # 1
print(get_smallest_num(5)) # 6
```

Answer (score 0):

`min((graph[key])[1])` works for me.

You can try : `min([x[1] for x in graph[key]])`